# Iphone keep getting "Incorrect Wi-Fi Password"

Tags: iphone, ios, network, wifi, password

Something strange happened to my little iphone 6s. This morning, everything was alright, wifi connectiong was perfect. I went on google and searched some info, send 5 photos to a friend through social net work. Then I went out for a walk for about 1:30 hours. After I came back home, my iphone couldn't get connect to wifi. I tried many many times. Always get "Incorrect Wi-Fi Password" or "uable to connect to WIFI". I restarted my iphone and router many times. IN Vain. Keep getting "Incorrect Wi-Fi Password". I observed that there is a red "i" on my software update. But since I have no wifi connection I can not finish the update. Guys, I am desperate. Some magic happened. Please help!!! THANK YOU ALL!!!

Comment: Clear down. Delete/forget the connection from the phone, try again. If no joy, change the password in the router. Set back up again. Report back.

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin, I tried delete/forget the conncetion, no success. I don't know how to change password in the router.  :(  Moreover other mobiles at home have no wifi connection problems. What else I can do? Thanks.